# how to write a cover letter for Canadian student visa application?

Tags: masters, application, visa

I have been accepted from a Canadian university and now I am applying for the visa.
I'd like to write a cover letter for visa application. Could you plz provide us a sample of cover letter for visa application and/or guide me about the content of the letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's called a "Study Plan". It should generally explain your goals and how your study plan fits into your academic and career plans in 1-2 pages, as per the Ankara Visa Office instructions ([source](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5816E.pdf)), though it might be different for applicants applying from different countries.

Based on that and what I found around the web, the following questions should typically be answered especially if you're not going to have an interview in person:

- Why do you wish to study in Canada in the program for which you
  have been accepted?
- What is your overall educational goal?
- Why are you not pursuing a similar program in your country of residence/citizenship?
- What research have you done into studies in your country of residence/citizenship?
- How will this program enhance your employment opportunities in
  your country of residence/citizenship?
- What ties do you have to your country of residence/citizenship?

Since the Study Permit is a temporary type of VISA, the purpose of the last question is to convince that you will leave Canada at the end of your studies.

There are also suggestions that one should write the Study Plan in this Q&A format instead of a traditional essay one in order to make it easier for the Officer to learn the information they need from you.

In some cases a separate cover letter about how you will fund your program and living might be a good idea if you're not fully-funded by the institution of your choice. (This is supplemented with the financial documents, such as bank statements, etc. that you've been asked to provide.)